# PHP vs JavaScript, Bitwise Operators

Tags: javascript, php, bitwise-operators

I have a function in JavaScript:

```
function myFunc(a, b, c)
{
  return (a ^ (b | (~c)));
}
```

And Equivalent in PHP:

```
function myFunc($a, $b, $c)
{
    return ($a ^ ($b | (~$c)));
}
```

The result for them are not the same:

```
myFunc('123', '4434', '355'); // PHP = ��� (Unknown Characters)
myFunc('123', '4434', '355'); // JavaScript = -91
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: From the manual: _if the operands are strings, then the operation will be performed on the ASCII values of the characters that make up the strings_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you need to cast manually to integer

```
function myFunc($a, $b, $c)
{
    return ((int)$a ^ ((int)$b | (~(int)$c)));
}
```